# Search array MongoDB NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, ejs

I am struggling to get records where the name matches the name i have stored an another database.
I can retrieve all fields of data but i am struggling to get specific records i.e. where name = either jack or jill.
I want to use a variable i take from my passport log in which i can access at req.user.username.

I tried using findOne and manipulating the ejs array without any luck.
It prints to the console but i cannot display on vieworders.ejs
I think i am overcomplicating, what is the best way to find and display records where applicationDB.name = req.user.username?

server.js is

```
app.get('/vieworders', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(), function(req, res) {
          Myapplication.find(function(err, myorders) {
          res.render('vieworders', { user: req.user, myorders: myorders});
          console.log(myorders);
      });
});
```

vieworders.ejs is

```
<h1> Display Orders Here </h1>
<% if(myorders.length>0) { %>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>size</th>

        </tr>
         <% for(var i=0; i<hurleys.length;i++) { %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= i %></td>
                  <td><%= myorders[i].name %></td>
                  <td><%= myorders[i].orderssize %></td>
                </tr>
                   <% } %>

</table>
<% } else { %>
        No Record Found
      <% } %>
```

MyApplication schema is

```
const mySchema= new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  ordersize: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('MyApplication', mySchema);
```

Comment: Hi, I think we need the Myapplication schema to provide an answer

Comment: Thanks, added schema!

Comment: So the answer should be correct from Nico de Ory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the query filter as the first parameter of the `find` method.

This should do the trick, assuming the username is stored in the Schema as `name`.

```
app.get('/vieworders', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(), function(req, res) {
          Myapplication.find({name: req.user.username}, function(err, myorders) {
          res.render('vieworders', { user: req.user, myorders: myorders});
          console.log(myorders);
      });
});
```

Comment: That worked! was trying that with FindOne with no luck, thanks so much!

Comment: `findOne` also works, but it will only return **one** record, so if you want to retrieve all orders from a specific user, `find` is what you're looking for.